# The location of standard Python libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries

It is stated in Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) that:

> By default, the libraries are searched in `prefix/lib/pythonversion` and `exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion`, where `prefix` and `exec_prefix` are installation-dependent directories, both defaulting to `/usr/local`.

But when I looked into my `/usr/local` directory, what I found was a folder named python2.7. I did install python3.5 not python2.7 on my device (MacBook mid 2012).

Answer (score 3):

You could use sys module to find that.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Ouput like:

```
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mccabe-0.3.1-py2.7.egg', ...
```

Comment: I know that but I'm asking why standard library files are not where they are supposed to be. In addition to that, why do I have the `python2.7` folder on my device?

Answer (score 2):

Mac comes with a default Python 2.7 installation. Your installation did not remove python2.7. Probably also the reason why the system libraries are not under usr/local.

Answer (score 1):

You never state how you attempted to install Python 3.5 onto your MacBook, depending on the installation options you used while building the Python source (or the bundle you downloaded) the install location could be different from the defaults.  If you provide further details on your installation method, it will be easier to answer all aspects of your question.

As far as I can tell, Apple does not use the installation defaults to provide Python with OSX.  On my OSX El Capitan machine, I can see the system Python library at /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 and the binary at /usr/bin/python (Python 2.7.x comes preinstalled for all recent versions of OSX).

It looks like the easiest way to get Python 3.5 on Mac is to use [MacPython](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html) which will install alongside the system version of Python (as you should not alter the default system version of Python or risk breaking OSX).  It installs some helper applications into your Finder's Applications directory and installs the library files to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5.  Since you will have more then one version of Python installed, you would also need to put some effort into making sure your scripts are using the proper version.

If you have a /usr/local/python2.7 directory, that sounds like something that was previously installed by a user.  If I remember correctly, OSX does not normally use /usr/local for system software.

Hope that helps

Comment: I installed python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/) as I can remember. I downloaded an installer which did the work. Is MacPython something different?

Comment: It looks like MacPython is what they call the official Mac OSX installer bundle which I can see in the link you included.  If that is what you used, you should check /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/ and see if it got installed there